# Baby Rudin Theorem 11.35

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Inside Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Rudin states

> **11.35** $\ \ $ **Theorem** $\ \ $ *Suppose $f\in{L}^2(\mu)$ and $g\in{L}^2(\mu)$. Then $fg \in{L}^1(\mu)$, and*
>
> $$\int_{X} \left|fg\right| d\mu \leq  \|f\| \|g\|.$$
>
> **Proof:** This is the Schwarz inequality, which we have already encountered
> for series and for Riemann integrals. It follows from the inequality
>
> $$0\leq \int_{X}(\left|f\right|+\lambda\left|g\right|)^2 d\mu=\|f\|^2+2\lambda\int_{X} \left|fg\right| d\mu+\lambda^2\|g\|^2$$
>
> which holds for every real $\lambda$.

One way to interpret the last equality on the RHS is through the discriminant of a quadratic equation for $\lambda$

$$\lambda*=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac\ }}{2a},$$

where $a,b,c$ are the coefficients of $\lambda$. If $\lambda$ is real, then the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ should be positive. This means that

$$b^2-4ac \geq 0.$$

When I do the analysis on pencil and paper, I find that

$$b^2 \geq 4ac,$$

and that

$$\int_{X} \left|fg\right| d\mu \geq  \|f\| \|g\|.$$

This is clearly wrong. Why am I getting the opposite of the Schwarz inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quadratic $P(\lambda)=\|f\|^2+2\lambda\int_{X} \left|fg\right| d\mu+\lambda^2\|g\|^2$ is always positive, so there can't be two distinct roots (otherwise $P(\lambda)$ would be negative for some values of $\lambda$).  Thus the discriminant must be $\leq0$.

Comment: $P(\lambda)$ needs not be a quadratic function in $\lambda$. The case $||g||=0$ needs to be handled separately (although it is easy..).

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Of course.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a specific theorem or resource I can review to see why the discriminant is negative? I reviewed Wikipedia. I don't understand why always being positive implies that the discriminant must be $\leq$ 0.

Comment: @Axion004 It's just elementary algebra:  since the binomial is always positive, it can have at most one real root, and if the discriminant were positive it would have two real roots.

Comment: I see, http://www.biology.arizona.edu/biomath/tutorials/quadratic/roots.html.